# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in angular ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, service

I have written the code below:

```
postData: function(value1) {
      return $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://my.url",
            data: value1,
            beforeSend: function(){},
            complete: function() {
              console.log("done");
            }
       });
}
```

And the error I receive is:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I call this service with:

```
Service.postData($rootScope.variable).then(function(res){
  console.log(res);
});
```

How can I solve the aforementioned problem?

Comment: you should be using `$http` instead of `$.ajax` with angularjs. E.g. `return $http.post("http://my.url", value1).then((res) => {console.log("done"); return res;}, (err) => {console.log("error")})`

Comment: `$` is the `syntactic  sugar` for jquery and angular doesn't supports jquery it only includes some of the function under `angular jqlite`.
You are using JS Framework so try using what it provides and create a service which is the best approach under which you have to call `$http`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create methods like this in angularJS Service:
someFuntion: function() {
                var url = 'Your URL';
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get(url, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data.data);
                }, function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
```